# Is it costly to read one full partition from Cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

Let say i am having one table

RecordingsByAccountaId ( AccountId, a,b,c,x,y,z)

Partitioning key : AccountId
Clustering key : a,b

I need to fetch data for one Account inside my code, so performing

Select * from RecordingsByAccountaId where accountId = 'accountId';

Is it a costly operation ???

Objective is to update 2-3 rows of this table but i don't have any information more then accountId.

Is it almost same to query one row or whole partition ? Because the time I saw to fetch between 200 rows n one row has difference of 20-30 milliseconds?

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly depend on the size of your partition - how many rows it includes.  Another factor is how fragmented is your partition - is it located in the single SSTable (it's compacted) or in the multiple SSTables, so you will read data from multiple files.

But usually, reading a partition inside the single file is sequential operation, as all rows that belong to same partition are written sequentially, and if partition size isn't very big, then the performance shouldn't suffer dramatically (but this may depend on your hardware as well).

P.S. How do you make decision on which rows you'll update?

Comment: Does this query: `select * from RecordingsByAccountaId where AccountId = 123 and a =1 and b = 2;` pull entire partition to memory and then return the single row requested or read just the single row to memory and return the row?

Comment: If it’s full primary key, as in your case, then it will read just a single row... But it may need to read data from multiple files to reconstruct the latest version, if parts of the row where updated.

Comment: And how can we compute data is coming from single SSTable or multiple ? 

Till What extent/Configuration we can say it's working fine ?

Partition size is in good state only , less then 100MB.

Comment: it depends on if you're just inserting data, or updating them, etc. Eventually, via compaction, data will be combined into fewer files.

Comment: If you look at `nodetool tablehistograms`, it will show you the percentiles of sstables per read for that table on that node. This doesn't show you a particular row but gives you an idea of how fragmented the data in your table is in general.  If p50 sstables per read is high then your performance will be degraded.  Also, to see the sstables read for a particular query you can look at tracing in cqlsh. Run `tracing on` then execute the query you want to analyze. It will show how many sstables each replica consulted.